# Inconsistent dark theme for GTK apps on 23.04

Tags: firefox, themes, gtk, flatpak, 23.04

I have encountered the following issue with using Flatpak apps on Ubuntu 23.04.

Basically, some (parts of) programs will pick up the dark mode I have selected in the settings, while others will not.

For example, here is Firefox: the title bar is correctly themed, the interactive debug thing is correctly themed, but the file picker dialog is not.

[Firefox Demo Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXuPm.png)

I tried changing gsettings to:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
'prefer-dark'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme
'Yaru-dark'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme
'Yaru-dark'
```

To no effect. Changing values in the Debug window only affects the title bar, does not affect the file picker.

Setting `GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark` in Flatseal had no effect.

Running Firefox manually by using

```
$ flatpak run --command=sh org.mozilla.firefox
[ org.mozilla.firefox ~]$ GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark firefox
```

Had no effect.

I have Yaru-dark installed in Flatpak (and it's the only theme I have installed in Flatpak):

```
$ flatpak list | grep -i gtk3theme
Yaru-dark Gtk Theme     org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru-dark             3.22    system
```

Did anyone else encounter a similar problem? How could this be solved?

Answer (score 7):

To answer my own question: this is happening due to the Ubuntu version of libadwaita not respecting the light/dark choice.

Here's a lauchpad bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libadwaita-1/+bug/2013126

I sent a patch to it, hope it can help

In the meantime, adding `ADW_DEBUG_COLOR_SCHEME=prefer-dark` to `/etc/environment` and rebooting should help.

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you. I wonder what are the side effects of this besides the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Gregory Khvatsky's answer, you can override the GTK theme for only flatpak applications by running

```bash
flatpak override --user --env=ADW_DEBUG_COLOR_SCHEME=prefer-dark
```

You may need to install a dark theme flatpak if your application doesn't provide one:

```bash
flatpak install org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Adwaita-dark
```

To back out of the change, run

```bash
flatpak override --user --unset-env=ADW_DEBUG_COLOR_SCHEME
```

No need to edit /etc/environment.